# Class 'EspressoDev\InstagramBasicDisplay\InstagramBasicDisplay' not found in instagram_block_cron() Error

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I am using Drupal 8.9 and a module named Instagram block.When i updated the module "Class 'EspressoDev\InstagramBasicDisplay\InstagramBasicDisplay' not found in instagram_block_cron() " error shows. My php version is 7.4. Is there any way to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can fix it. **Here** is the command for it:

```
composer require espresso-dev/instagram-basic-display-php
```

<sup>*( ^^^ The above command downloads: [espresso-dev/instagram-basic-display-php](https://github.com/espresso-dev/instagram-basic-display-php))*</sup>